# Why database replication optimizes reading and writing from the database?

Tags: postgresql, database-replication

Can someone explain why database replication usually optimizes reading and writing from the database? I can not understand how it works... after all, replication adds a lot of extra operations, such as master-slave marge. The type of database I'm considering is a PostgreSQL cloud-based database, making `1.5M` records per day, only `1%` of this records is a reading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL replication does not optimize reading and writing.

You can use it for load balancing, but it is not perfect for that:

- your application has to know that is must write to one database and read from another
- data written at the primary server don't become visible at the standby right away

If your workload consists to 99% of writing, that won't help you at all.

Look into sharding if you want to distribute the load.

Comment: So, postreSQL can only help with load balancing and it never speeds up reading-services? Or did you say it only about my problem?

Comment: No, I wrote the opposite: streaming replication can only be used for load balancing with reading, not with writing.